# Height of div container fitting screen

Tags: css, html

I created the following layout:

[image]

What I want to achieve is, that the red and the blue container have a 100% height inside the wrapper. This is the HTML code so far:

```
@extends('master.main')

<!-- Section Insert for pageTitle -->
@section('pageTitle')
    title
@endsection

<!-- Section Insert for content -->
@section('content')
    <div class="menu-bar"></div>
    <div class="main-content">
        <div class="row row-no-padding">
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <div class="content-container-left">test</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <div class="content-container-right">test</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

And the Styling:

```
#main-content-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 60px;
  background-color: #f7f8f9;
}

.main-content {
  margin-left: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.content-container-left {
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
}

.content-container-right {
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
}

.row-no-padding {
  [class*="col-"] {
    padding-left: 0 !important;
    padding-right: 0 !important;
  }
}
```

I tried to understand the logic how to achieve this, but still have issues as I do not have the most experience yet with that. I thought about a height setting of 100%, which does not work. But I do not understand why is that?

Answer (score 0):

If the parent element is static then the height will be auto. If you have the parent element `position: absolute` and set fix height you will see 100% means it will fill the height of the parent of block element.

Please note by default block level element position is static (example div, h1, h2).

Please this documentation: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-height-property

Comment: But I want the parent to be always in screen height. If I would set a fixed height, wouldn't that be contradictory?

Comment: Use 100% on all the parents up to the <html> itself. <html> will get it's height from the window, and the rest will kinda inherit it.

Comment: What kind of browser are you [supporting](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)? You can try this css3 `height: 100vh;` That will fill the entire height of view port.  [css example](http://jsfiddle.net/e4py5gej/)

Answer (score 0):

For

```
height: 100%;
```

to work, you need to have an explicitly set height on the parent element.

I'd suggest:

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
}

.main-content,
.main-content > .row,
.main-content > .row > div {
    height: 100%;
}

.content-container-left,
.content-container-right{
    height: 100%;
}
```